# What math knowledge should I have before starting reading "Algebra and Trigonometry" by Stewart?

Tags: book-recommendation

I want to read "Algebra and Trigonometry" by Stewart. What math knowledge should I have before starting reading "Algebra and Trigonometry" by Stewart?

Answer (score 2):

From the frontmatter of the textbook itself, it states:

> To succeed in your Algebra and Trigonometry course you need to use
> some of the skills that you learned in your previous mathematics
> classes. In particular, you need to be familiar with the real number
> system, algebraic expressions, solving basic equations, and graphing.

It then goes on to provide several diagnostic tests which "are designed to assess your knowledge of these topics". They give the following recommendation:

> After taking each test you can check your answers using the answer key
> on page xxii. If you have difficulty with any topic, you can refresh
> your skills by studying the review materials from Chapters P and I
> that are referenced after each test.